# Laravel get TimeZone not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, timezone, laravel-3

Iam trying to convert `UTC` timezone to `Singapore Time`

```
    echo $Date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    echo '<br>'; 
    echo with(new Carbon\Carbon($Date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')))->tz('Asia/Singapore')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    exit;
```

it works fine in `Localhost` but in `aws server` it displays `utc Time` for both...Both server and Localhost is set to `UTC` Time .. how do we fix this??

Comment: I don't want to be rude but why would you tagged all laravel versions? First of all your question has nothing to do with Laravel. Possibly because Carbon comes default in composer in laravel4 but laravel3 has nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it will work

```
 $timestamp ='1411205843'  //Timestamp which you need to convert 

 $sourceTimezone = new DateTimeZone('UTC');

 $destinationTimezone = new DateTimeZone('Asia/Singapore'); 

 $dt = new DateTime(date('m/d/Y h:i A', $timestamp), $sourceTimezone);
 $dt->setTimeZone($destinationTimezone);

 echo strtotime($dt->format('m/d/Y h:i A'));
```

Comment: Why in the world would you mix up `DateTime` class with `date()` and `strtotime()` functions? This can be simply solved using only `DateTime` class... **[DEMO](https://eval.in/197869)**

Answer (score 2):

I assume that `$Date` in your case is `DateTime` object (or `Carbon` object). You can use PHP `setTimeZone()` and `DateTimeZone`:

```
$Date = new DateTime($user->updated_at); // sample DateTime creation - also $Date = $user->updated_at; would work here

echo $Date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s")."<br />";

$Date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Singapore'));
echo  $Date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s")."<br />";
```

For me it generates:

```
2014-09-19 12:06:15
2014-09-19 20:06:15
```

Answer (score 1):

I assumed that, the `$Date` variable you have is a [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) (By default available in `Laravel`) object:

```
$Date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Now to set the `timezone` you may use any one of these:

```
$Date->timezone = new DateTimeZone('Asia/Singapore');
$Date->timezone = 'Asia/Singapore';
$Date->tz = 'Asia/Singapore';
```

You may also set it from your `app/config/app.php` like:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Timezone
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
| will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
| ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
|
*/

'timezone' => 'Asia/Singapore',
```

Comment: For laravel 5.8 route to app.php file is just: config/app.php

Answer (score 0):

You can set to session like below;

```
 Session::put('timezone', 'Your/TimeZone');
```

Enjoy your Code !